# Parent item toggles child item as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this sortable item list using Jquery UI Sortable, which is also able to nest items.

Each of these items contains toggable content, it will slide down when clicking on an item. However, when clicking on the parent item when nested, instead of only toggling the parent content it's also toggling the child's content.

I've been trying to figure it out in my Jquery script but haven't been able to figure it out.. I reproduced my issue in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/es3hbdnm/32/

Also HTML:

```
<ol class="sortable panel-group">
  <li class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="toggle">Home</div>
    <div class="panel-content">Hidden content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="toggle">About us</div>
    <div class="panel-content">Hidden content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="toggle">Contact</div>
    <div class="panel-content">Hidden content</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
  handle: 'div',
  items: 'li',
  toleranceElement: '> div'
});


  $(".panel-default").click(function () {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(".panel-content").not($(this)).slideUp();

    $(this).find(".panel-content").slideDown();
  });

});
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code in in your question instead of giving external links

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check if the element is visible or not using `is(':visible')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
                handle: 'div',
                items: 'li',
                toleranceElement: '> div'
              });


            $(".panel-default").click(function () {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $(".panel-content").not($(this)).slideUp();
                let x = $(this).find(".panel-content");
                if(!x.is(':visible')) x.slideDown();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Mm, still producing the same issue. Parent and child are having toggle issue.

Comment: @Grek Json I can't understand what you mean. What you want to happen if **Home** is clicked

Comment: First you have to drag an item to be nested below another item. Then when clicking on the parent item to show it's hidden content, it also shows the content from the child.. which does not need to happen.

Comment: Mm no one able to help me out with this?